# how to implement timer in c++

Tags: c++, linux, timer

i'm working on gesture recognition application and i would like to implement timer but i don't know how.

here is what i want to do: user should be showing one gesture for 3 seconds before next function happens.

now it looks like this:

```
if(left_index==1)                 
{
putText("correct",Point(95,195),FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,0.8,Scalar(0,255,0),1,CV_AA);
correct = true;
}
break;
```

i would like it to be like this: `if(left_index==1)` <- if this is true for 3 seconds than the {} happens.

thank you for help.

Comment: save time, compare time, clear time. and most importantly: google/search.

Comment: Could you incorporate how you're checking for the gesture shown into you sample?

Comment: i'm comparing gestures recognized from video to the ones learned through examples. the if(left_index==1) compares that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Whatever your context is ...
if(left_index==1)
{
    clock_t init, now;

    init=clock();
    now=clock();
    while((left_index==1) && ((now-init) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) < 3))
    {
        sleep(100); // give other threads a chance!
        now=clock();
    }
    if((left_index==1) && (now-init) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) >= 3))
    {
        // proceed with stuff
        putText
          ( "correct"
          , Point(95,195)
          , FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,0.8,Scalar(0,255,0),1,CV_AA);
        correct = true;        
    }
}
```

For [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) I'd prefer a solution involving the classes from `std::chrono` instead working with `time.h`.

Comment: yep... there was some minor typing errors, but it works...thanks again...:)

Answer (score 1):

there is a built-in function called sleep. It will kind of put your program at rest for int x milliseconds

I will make a function wait(int seconds):

```
void wait(long seconds)
{
    seconds = seconds * 1000;
    sleep(seconds);
}
```

wait(1); //waits for 1 second or 1000 milliseconds

Comment: sleep isn't ok.
i need the app to run anyway...
sleep just pauses the process as far as i know.

Comment: I'd change the code a bit to make it clearer that `sleep()` takes milliseconds. Also reusing parameters locally on the stack isn't really good programming style!

Comment: @user2961826 Could you elaborate why? Your question doesn't explain your requirement exactly then IMHO.

Comment: the if statement has to be true for whole 3 seconds before action happens. with sleep it's true just the first moment and then pause for 3 seconds. sorry for my bad english...:)
its a real time gesture recognition from video.

Comment: @user2961826 So what? You can check it first time, sleep 3 secs and check a second time, if the condition is still true in the second check you can proceed. Or did I misunderstand s.th.? Do you wan't to enable cancellation of the gesture before 3s are over? Have a look at my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try doing the following :

```
#include <time.h>

clock_t init, final;

init=clock();
//
// do stuff
//
final=clock()-init;
cout << (double)final / ((double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Check these links out for further reference :

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/317/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/

Answer (score 0):

assuming your app is running an update loop.

```
bool gesture_testing = false;
std::chrono::time_point time_start;

while(app_running) {
  if (! gesture_testing) {
    if (left_index == 1) {
      gesture_testing = true;
      time_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
  } else {
    if (left_index != 1) {
      gesture_testing = false;
    } else {
      auto time_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(time_end - time_start);
      if (duration.count() == 3) {
        // do gesture function
        gesture_testing = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is the basic logic, you can write a timer class and refactor the body into one function to make room for other part of your app.